# Displaying results for tic tac toe app

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm currently writing a program that creates the game tic tac toe. The app as it is right now has two people play at against each other, taking turns entering the row and column number. The main problem I'm having with this program is that I cannot get it to display the results of whether one person wins or loses or both players tie. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can solve this that would be great. Thanks again for your time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ticTacToeApp {
    // 1. GAME CONSTANTS
    static final int WIN = 1;
    static final int LOSE = 0;
    static final int TIE = 2;
    static final int GAME_IN_PROGRESS = 3;
    static final String PLAYER = "X";
    static final String OPPONENT = "O";
    static final String EMPTY = " ";
    // 2. INPUT STREAM
    static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 3. BUILD THE TIC TAC TOE 3X3 BOARD OF STRINGS
        String[][] board = { { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY }, { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },{EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY } };
        // 4. INSTANTIATE THE SCANNER FOR INPUT
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // 5. GAME ENGINE
        drawBoard(board);
        int moveResult = GAME_IN_PROGRESS; // STATUS OF THE GAME AND AFTER A
                                            // MOVE
        while (moveResult == GAME_IN_PROGRESS) {
            // PLAYER MOVES AND BOARD IS CHECKED FOR A RESULT
            getMove(board, PLAYER, in);
            drawBoard(board);
            if (moveResult != GAME_IN_PROGRESS)
                break;

            // OPPONENT MOVES AND THE BOARD IS CHECKED FOR A RESULT
            getMove(board, OPPONENT, in);
            drawBoard(board);
            moveResult = boardResults(board);
        }
        // 6. ONCE THE GAME HAS ENDED, DISPLAY IT IS AS A WIN, LOSE, OR TIE.
        if (moveResult == WIN)
            System.out.println("You win.");
        else if (moveResult == LOSE)
            System.out.println("You lost.");
        else
            System.out.println("You tied.");
    }

    public static int boardResults(String[][] board) {
        // TASK 1: BUILD AN ARRAY CONTAINING ALL THE ROW, COLUMN, AND
        // DIAGONAL STRING ARRANGEMENTS ON THE CURRENT
        // TIC TAC TOE BOARD.
        String[] waysToWin = new String[8];
        int i = 0; // INDEX TO wayToWin
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            String str = " ", stc = " ";
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                str += board[r][c];
                stc += board[c][r];
            }
            waysToWin[i++] = str;
            waysToWin[i++] = stc;

            // ADD 2 DIAGONALS
            waysToWin[i++] = board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2];
            waysToWin[i++] = board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0];
            // TASK 2. CHECK IF ANY OF THESE ARRANGEMENTS CONTAIN A WINNING
            // "XXX" OR
            // "OOO"
            // NOTE: AN "XXX" IS WIN AND AN "OOO" IS LOSE.
            for (int p = 0; p < 8; p++) {
                if (waysToWin[p].equals("XXX"))
                    return WIN;
                if (waysToWin[p].equals("OOO"))
                    return LOSE;
                // TASK 3. CHECK IF THE BOARD IS FULL (TIE) OR IF THE GAME IS
                // STILL IN
                // PROGRESS
                if (board[0][0] == EMPTY || board[0][1] == EMPTY || board[0][2] == EMPTY || board[1][0] == EMPTY
                        || board[1][1] == EMPTY || board[1][2] == EMPTY || board[2][0] == EMPTY || board[2][1] == EMPTY
                        || board[2][2] == EMPTY)
                    return GAME_IN_PROGRESS;

            }
        }
        return i;

    }

    public static void drawBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            System.out.println("___________");
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print("|" + board[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("| ");
        }
        System.out.println("___________");
    }

    public static void getMove(String[][] board, String whoseMove, Scanner in) {
        int[] xy = new int[2];
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("You are " + whoseMove + ". ");
            System.out.println("Enter the row and column of your move: ");
            xy[0] = in.nextInt();
            xy[1] = in.nextInt();
            if (board[xy[0]][xy[1]].equals(EMPTY))
                break;
            System.out.println("You must choose an empty space.");
        }
        board[xy[0]][xy[1]] = whoseMove;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single dimensional array for the board and create an array of winning combinations that indexes into the board. Then loop through the winning combinations and count X's and O's. If you have 3, then declare a winner. Here is a snippet demonstrating:

```
public class ticTacToeApp {
  static final String X = "X";
  static final String O = "O";
  static final String N = " ";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] board = { X,X,O,
        N,O,N,
        O,N,N };

    // combinations to win: 
    int[][] wins = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,6,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6} };

    // count x's and o's to win
    int x=0, o=0;

    // find the winner by indexing the board array from the combinations to win array
    // In each combination to win, if all 3 are X's or O's, declare a winner

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
      x=0; o=0;
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
        if (board[wins[i][j]] == X) x++;          
        if (board[wins[i][j]] == O) o++;    
      }
      if (o==3 || x==3) 
        System.out.println(((x==3) ? "X" : "O") + " wins");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not too shabby on your first answer Royce, yes. big brother is watching you :)